# jQuery Mobile - Link does not work

Tags: jquery

I am testing the following code to open a panel from w3schools. It works fine on the laptop but when I load it on my Android Note 3 device, the panel does not show when you touch the Open Panel link, nothing happens! Any help please?
Sinan

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.4/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.4/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page" id="pageone">
  <div data-role="panel" id="myPanel"> 
    <h2>Panel Header</h2>
    <p>You can close the panel by clicking outside the panel, pressing the Esc key or by swiping.</p>
  </div> 

  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Page Header</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <p>Click on the button below to open the Panel.</p>
    <a href="#myPanel" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all ui-shadow">Open Panel</a>
  </div>

  <div data-role="footer">
    <h1>Page Footer</h1>
  </div> 
</div> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you using webview? If not this is not an Android question, get your tags right.

Comment: I am using Phonegap to generate an apk file to be loaded onto an Android device. Changed the tag to jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility that you opened your app in device without having internet connection in it. I am saying because you have used some libraries those are located in jquery repo. Try with Internet connection or simply download them and link them and see.

Comment: Thank you anupam. The device is connected to the Internet.

Comment: anupam: I took your advice for downloading the files locally and it worked fine. Many thanks.